# Small question regarding subspaces of order topology

Tags: general-topology

When looking at $Y:=\left(0,1\right)\cup\left\{ 2\right\} 
 $ with the subspace topology induced by the order topology on $\mathbb{R}$ one immediately sees that $2$ is an isolated point of $Y$. Contrary to that, according to another thread I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83530/if-x-is-an-order-topology-and-y-subset-x-is-closed-do-the-subspace-topolog) when you look at $Y$ with the order topology induced by restricting the order on $\mathbb{R}$ to $Y$ then $2$ is not an isolated point. But to me it seems that in said topology since $2$ is the maximal element of $Y$ one gets that $\left\{ 2\right\} =\left(1,2\right]$ is an open set and thus $2$ should be isolated.

I have a feeling I'm missing something very silly and I apologize if the question might seem trivial to some.

Comment: There is no $1$ in that set. The neighbourhoods of $2$ are generated by $\lbrace (x,\, \infty) \colon x < 2\rbrace$. In its own order topology, that set is homeomorphic to $(0,\,1]$.

Comment: Wow that is extremely silly of me to not notice that... I have been studying for a topology exam for about a week now. Maybe I haven't been taking enough breaks... 
Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2$ is not isolated in the order topology. To see this, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $2$ in the order topology. Recall that the open sets in the order topology are unions of open intervals and open rays, so $U$ must contain either an open interval or an open ray containing $2$. Clearly no open interval in $Y$ contains $2$, nor does any open ray in the negative direction, so $U$ must contain some open ray of the form $(a,\infty)$ which contains $2$. **Note that $a$ must be in $Y$.** Thus since $a<2$ we have $a<1$, so $\frac{a+1}{2}\in U$. Since every neighborhood of $2$ contains a point other than $2$, $2$ is not isolated.

Comment: A remark: my definition of the order topology (more usual) is that is generated by the open rays (in 2 directions), as a subbase. The open intervals are then intersections of 2 rays, so in the generated base (we only need consider intersections of 2 rays, as a finite intersection of rays in one direction is again a ray (of the max or min), so finite intersections of rays come down to the intersection of 2 at most. This is nicer for Alexander's subbase lemma e.g. Proving compactness for $[0,1]$ is then almost trivial.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm familiar. But for my remark I required the use of a base. I understand "generated by" to mean "consists of unions of" but perhaps this is nonstandard.

Comment: generated for me is like a subbase. So the smallest topology containing all rays. The generated base is then all finite intersections of those (including the empty and one-set intersections!) and then we take all unions. Otherwise I just say we have a base for the topology, instead of a subbase.

Comment: I also tend to think about the term "generated" as "consists of unions of" like Alex said but in the case of a subbase the term is actually "consists of finite intersections".
In the Topology course I took the emphasis was completely on bases and the subject of subbases was barely explored so it's probably a result of that.

Comment: @Serpahimz in both cases it means "the smallest topology containing the family", so it's really the same thing in the end.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer by the way Alex.